# workfront API updating Users task time in their time sheet

Tags: api

I want to update a tasks work hours and have it also update that task on the users assigned time sheet.

I get the user's time sheet id and I call https://*********.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/hour?

Posting

```
[taskID] => 55e06e67001af6e*********
[timesheetID] => 55d0283a0022************
[entryDate] => 2015-08-28
[hours] => 3
[apiKey] => *****************
```

This successfully updates the the task actual hours but it does not update the task field in the users time sheet.

However if I get the user time sheet for the current period

```
data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 55d0283a00223e********
                [displayName] => ********** 8/23/15 - 8/29/15
                [objCode] => TSHET
                [approverID] => 551b350d************************
                [customerID] => 52fe8***************************
                [endDate] => 2015-08-29
                [extRefID] => 
                [hasNotes] => 
                [hoursDuration] => 48
                [lastNoteID] => 
                [lastUpdateDate] => 2015-08-15T23:05:46:727-0700
                [lastUpdatedByID] => 
                [overtimeHours] => 0
                [regularHours] => 10
                [startDate] => 2015-08-23
                [status] => O
                [timesheetProfileID] => 54ed0********************
                [totalHours] => 10
                [userID] => 551f********************
            )

    )
```

The total hours is updated, but the timesheet in the web gui does not reflect that anywhere.

I need to update the task and the user time sheet with hours worked on an assigned task.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the hourTypeID field in the post.  This works for v9 at least.

The hourType is used in WF/AtTask for determining whether an hour is a project hour, a task hour, or an overhead hour (which in itself has different types -- some of them custom to a particular organization).  You can see what kinds of hourTypes you have here:

https://*********.my.workfront.com/attask/api/v9.0/hourType/search?isActive=true

I usually filter the query further, but I hope this is a good starting point for anyone reading.

I know this was posted a while back but I was working with updating timesheets over the past week and thought this may be helpful.